# What is the easiest way to post code in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown, ease-of-use

Most of the times in order to give an answer or ask a question, I write code. But, writing code directly to the answer's  textbox is quite tedious. I have to type too much spaces in order to get the code correctly indented (this helps users who read the code ). So, there are some trick, some format tag, anything, to help community write code easier?

Comment: copy and paste your code from an editor

Comment: click the "help" button next to your text box it looks like a orange question mark box sometimes

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I'm curious.  Does Raydel miranda get notifications for this post?  Will He/She be aware of it's existance in meta?

Comment: @SamIam Nope. There's no account here.

Comment: He can follow the link from the question on SO. I probably won't get my answer accepted though :P.

Comment: Yep. The migration stub is still there.

Comment: Yes I get notifications for this post. Thanks for your answers and sorry for such as question. I have been working all night and am really tired, I just post what come in to my mind following an old habit: "Always post something before go to bed" :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way is to copy and paste your code into the editor window, select what you pasted, and then click the {} button. This turns it into a code field.

You sometimes have to do some minor editing for fixing tabs, but it generally works pretty well.

If you just want to put one word in a code field, like a variable name, then surround it with backticks ("`").

As suggested in the comments, you definitely want to edit the code in the IDE and then paste it in. Editing the code in the window is a real pain, so minimize how much of that you have to do.

Comment: Most editors let you select text and tab left or right. If you tab the text so that the first line is flush with your editing window.. you can copy and paste it directly into the SO editor and no formatting will be required.

Comment: You might also want to note that when composing code for an answer, you can open up your IDE, and compose there, rather than directly on the page.

Comment: Also note that there are some problems with code formatting in SO code, created with `{}` button (at least for python code) if it's formatted with tab symbols instead for 4 spaces.

Comment: CnP matters (at least) as much of accuracy as ease. Re-typing code often results in typos that distract from the real problem at hand.

Comment: I recommend converting tabs to spaces before copying. Tabs can be interpreted as 2, 3, 4 or 8 common spaces.